# Unity Image unmasking game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a game where an image is hidden in the start and slowly parts of it is unmasked at random until the whole image is visible.

Like an image is divided into grid and one by one whole grid starts to unmask.

I tried to slice an image into several images and assign a new layer to each of the image, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" is rather vague.

Comment: Doesn't work as in, I am adding different layer to each image and it is not rendering in the scene based on the culling layer.
Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: I think it would be pretty easy to do if you just overlaid an opaque image and started changing random pixels to alpha color.

Comment: @Voidsay I am don't know how to do it, do you have any reference?

Comment: @apollo As most things it depends if you are working with UI, Sprites or 3d meshes. There is a bit of a process to it. You can read about texture modification here [Texture2D.SetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html), perhaps this will be enough for you to be inspired to do it yourself.